# How to use widgets to pass dynamic column names in Dataframe select statement

Tags: sql, scala, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a Dataframe and I want to dynamically pass the columns names through widgets in a select statement in my Databricks Notebook. How can I do it?

I am using the below code

```
df1 = spark.sql("select * from tableraw")
```

where `df1` has columns "tablename" and "layer"

```
df = df1.select("tablename", "layer")
```

Now, our requirement is to use the values of the widgets to select those columns, something like:

```
df = df1.select(dbutils.widget.get("tablename"), dbutils.widget.get("datalayer"))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Python / Scala

#### Create Widgets

```py
%python
dbutils.widgets.text(name = "pythonTextWidget", defaultValue = "columnName")
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name = "pythonDropdownWidget", defaultValue = "col1", choices = ["col1", "col2", "col3"])
```

```scala
%scala
dbutils.widgets.text("scalaTextWidget", "columnName")
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("scalaDropdownWidget", "col1", Seq("col1", "col2", "col3"))
```

#### Extract Value from Widgets

```py
%python
textColumn = dbutils.widgets.get("pythonTextWidget")
dropdownColumn = dbutils.widgets.get("pythonDropdownWidget")
```

```scala
%scala
val textColumn = dbutils.widgets.get("scalaTextWidget")
val dropdownColumn = dbutils.widgets.get("scalaDropdownWidget")
```

#### Use Value to select Column

```py
%python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.select(col(textColumn), col(dropdownColumn))
```

```scala
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
df.select(col(textColumn), col(dropdownColumn))
```

## SQL

The Widgets in SQL work slightly different compared to Python/Scala in the sense that you cannot use them to select a column. However, widgets can be used to dynamically adjust filters.

#### Create Widget

```sql
%sql CREATE WIDGET text sqlTextWidget DEFAULT "ACTIVE"
```

```sql
%sql CREATE WIDGET DROPDOWN sqlDropdownWidget DEFAULT "ACTIVE" CHOICES SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM <databaseName>.<tableName> WHERE Status IS NOT NULL
```

#### Apply Widget Value to Filter Statement

```sql
%sql SELECT * FROM <databaseName>.<tableName> WHERE Status = getArgument("sqlTextWidget")
```

More background can be found on the Databricks documentation on [Widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html).